# Populate drop-down list with MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to use the following code to populate a drop-down list with all of the customer types:

```
<select name="type" id="type" class="neutral">
<?php   // SQL QUERY TO RETRIEVE EVERY TYPE OF CUSTOMER
$sql = "SELECT CUST_TYPE FROM `CUSTOMER` GROUP BY `CUST_TYPE`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){echo '<option value="'.$row.'">'.$row.'</option>';}
                ?>
```

The query works in phpMyAdmin; it gives the correct output (corporate, other, school, sports) but in the webpage it displays a drop-down list with 4 options, all containing the word "array." Please help!

Comment: `print_r($row)` to see what is in there -- it is a 2D array, so you need  `$row['CUST_TYPE']`

Comment: Holy cow! Yup, that was it :) Good job!

Comment: A side note about your query - you are not using any [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and so although your `GROUP BY` probably gives you the result you expect, more appropriate would be to `SELECT DISTINCT CUST_TYPE FROM CUSTOMER`

Comment: Thank you very much Michael Berkowski!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<option value="'.$row['CUST_TYPE'].'">'.$row['CUST_TYPE'].'</option>';
}
```